# How can I have different values for the chart and the tooltip in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I want to use a radar chart from chart.js to display several attributes compared to average values.

For example, I might want to display the `size`, `weight` and `ipd` (interpupillary distance) of a specific human compared to the average.

Now, if I simply put in the raw numbers into the chart, that would look pretty weird, because the values of each of the attributes can't be compared with each other and would stretch the radar diagram in a weird way. So what I do instead is take a ratio from every attribute and put it in as data. For example this could mean that I have a size of `1.10` if someone is 10% taller than average, or a weight of `0.95`, if someone is 5% lighter than average.

But now when hovering over the data point, the tooltip shows the ratio that I put in as data value, so the tooltip would tell me `Size: 1.10`. I would like to have the real value in the tooltip instead, like `Size: 1.85m`.

How can I have a 'tooltip value' that is different from the actual `data` that is used for drawing the chart? My current code is below.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="chart-human"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-human');
var data = {
    labels: ['Size', 'Weight', 'IPD'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Sam Smith',
            data: [1.10, 0.95, 1.23]
        },
        {
            label: 'Average',
            data: [1, 1, 1]
        }
    ]
};
var options = {};
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could accomplish that using **[tooltip's callbacks](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration)** function ...

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-human');

var real_data = [
    ['1.85m', '100lbs', '120%'],
    ['1.95m', '90lbs', '150%']
];

var data = {
    labels: ['Size', 'Weight', 'IPD'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Sam Smith',
        data: [1.10, 0.95, 1.23],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,119,204,0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,119,204, 0.5)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'
    }, {
        label: 'John Doe',
        data: [1.20, 0.85, 1.43],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'
    }, {
        label: 'Average',
        data: [1, 1, 1],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.15)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.45)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'
    }]
};

var options = {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function(t, d) {
                let title = d.datasets[t[0].datasetIndex].label;
                return title;
            },
            label: function(t, d) {
                let title = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                let label = d.labels[t.index];
                let value = (title != 'Average') ? real_data[t.datasetIndex][t.index] : d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];
                return label + ': ' + value;
            }
        }
    }
};

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-human"></canvas>
```